# Initialize pseudo-random generator with a string

Tags: python, random

I would like to initialize a pseudo-random generator with a string. Say, I wish I could write something like `random.seed('Lorem ipsum')`.

I need a function that transforms a string (any alphanumeric string) in an integer. Is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: function that maps a string (any alphanumeric string) in an integer - any hash function, i.e. `md5`, and `hexdigest()`?

Comment: Thank you. Hash function is the concept I need. (I am not a programmer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [python2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed):

> `random.seed(a=None)` [...] If a is not None or an int or a long, then hash(a) is used instead

so you **can** use `random.seed("Lorem ipsum")` which would be the same as `random.seed(hash("Lorem ipsum"))`

Comment: Warning: Python 3.2 moved away from using `hash(a)` for `random.seed(a)`. The docs say this was to use more bits of `a` (`hash()` only outputs 64 bits) but it also facilitated that randomisation of `hash()` starting with Python 3.3 that would have broken `random.seed()` with seeds that will be hashed.

Comment: To initialise current Python 2 and Python 3 the same way, see @Anil_M 's answer.

Comment: Added a new answer with more detail on Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

In case secured hash of a string is needed, here is an example.
More on secure hash functions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)

```
import random
import hashlib

def md5hash(aString):    
    #hash string using FIPS secure hash algorithm (sha256)
    h = hashlib.sha256(aString)
    #Convert to numeric
    n = int(h.hexdigest(),base=16)
    return n

s = 'Lorem ipsum'

h = md5hash(s)
random.seed(h)

print random.randint(1,h)
```

> Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > 55515536588238178253973576746556262163439168431854287257541058247489753668463

Comment: While it's ugly, it is needed to get the same initialisation with current Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Squeezed into one line: `random.seed(int(hashlib.sha256(s).hexdigest(), 16))`

Answer (score 1):

As well as the suggestions Dmitry offers, why not just the built-in `hash` function?

```
print(hash('lorem ipsum'))` # 1163776412
```

Comment: just a note, the python builtin `hash` is not considered cryptographically secure and should not be used for sensitive data

Comment: `hash()` is randomised starting with Python 3.3. Run twice, get different hash values. Good for the reasons why it was introduced. Bad for reproducible results. (However, if output depend on undocumented behaviour or timing you are lost anyway. Some issues such as the order of dictionary keys can be fixed by setting `PYTHONHASHSEED` but not all.)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2

A string passed to `random.seed()` is hashed to a 64 bit number. Two different strings may hash to the same 64 bit number and therefore initialise the random number generator the same way. The more string seeds we try, the higher the probability to observe such a hash collision. Checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem, the probability is still very low if the number of seeds is small so we usually can live with it. To be on the safe side, however, the following initialisation code reduces the collision probability by more than 10^60: `random.seed(int(hashlib.sha512(mystringseed).hexdigest(), 16))`

## Python 3

Python 3.2 changed the initialisation from string seeds to not use Python's built-in `hash()` function. The documentation says that all bits of the seed string are used. It is not clear what happens if the string is longer than the length of the internal state of the random number generator, for example if only the first few hundred characters are used. (Hashing uses all characters.) Since `hash()` is no longer used, the randomisation of `hash()` introduced with Python 3.3 does not affect `random.seed()`. Still, the change in Python 3.2 means that a different sequence of random numbers is generated in Python 2 and Python >= 3.2 with the same string seed. When the seed is an integer, however, the initialisation is always the same.

## Solution

As integer seeds are used the same way in current Python 2 and Python 3, `random.seed(int(hashlib.sha512(mystringseed).hexdigest(), 16))` will allow reproduction of results with both Python 2 and Python >= 3.2.